# Capturing FFmpeg Progress with Progress Bar in C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I'm working on a C# application where I'm using FFmpeg to encode multiple video files. I want to display a progress bar to show the encoding progress for each video. I have tried using the Process.OutputDataReceived event to capture FFmpeg's progress updates, but it doesn't seem to work reliably.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
// Code snippet
int i = 1;
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    progressBar1.Maximum = openFileDialog1.FileNames.Length;

    foreach (string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
    {
        // Output file naming code here

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Progress parsing code here
            // This part doesn't seem to receive any data
        };

        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();

        i++;
    }
}
```

However, the OutputDataReceived event doesn't seem to receive any data from FFmpeg's stderr, and the progress bar doesn't update as expected.

Is there a better way to capture FFmpeg's progress updates for encoding videos and use them to update the progress bar in C#? How can I achieve this?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [Process.ErrorDataReceived Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: You need `process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true` to make the process redirect standard output.

Comment: I did but still not working.

Comment: Do you specify necessary arguments? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74952549/3137337

Comment: @emoacht Tried it.

Comment: set `RedirectStandardError` to true, and read progress from `OutputErrorReceived `